# Run Vim on Ubuntu:E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect

Tags: vim, ubuntu-16.04, pathogen

I have a simple `.vimrc` file. It is 3 lines in its entirety:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

When I try to start vim, though, I get the following error message:

```
Error detected while processing /home/simoonp/.vimrc:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
E15: Invalid expression: pathogen#infect()
```

I searched many means , but the question hasn't been solved.

Comment: Do you have `~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim`?

Comment: I do not have, should I create it ?

Comment: Yes you should create it and fill it with the content f this file: https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/blob/master/autoload/pathogen.vim

Comment: Did you *even* read pathogen's README?

Comment: thanks your advice and link, I solve my question.